# Python: obliviate user input that has become obsolete

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, user-input

I created my version of the game all beginners at Python play: Battleship.
The user must define two coordinates, X and Y.

I have made a validation, which rejects any input that is not an integer. If input is integer, the code continues to execute. At the end, however, I need to hardcode the current user input in a string, or else the code will not enter the while loop and re-prompt the user for another set of coordinates when the next turn starts.

This in fact works just fine, yet I feel like this is not the cleanest way to handle this.

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

```
# ships are positioned, user must sink them

for turn in range(num_of_turns):
    print("Turn", turn + 1)
    while type(guess_col) is not int:
        try:
            guess_col = input("Enter coordinate X: ")
            guess_col = int(guess_col)
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter coordinate X again")
            continue
    while type(guess_row) is not int:
        try:
            guess_row = input("Enter coordinate Y: ")
            guess_row = int(guess_row)
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter coordinate Y again")
            continue

        # do stuff (sink ships, miss ships, etc...)

    guess_col = str(guess_col)
    guess_row = str(guess_row)
```

Comment: @Artem his code does, in fact, provide all of those things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to set `guess_col` to something that isn't an `int` just before the while loop:

```
guess_col = ''
while ...:
```

I suggest that you learn about functions. These are a very important tool that helps you to organize code into small, coherent, reusable pieces. For example, you can write a function `get_int()` which does the validation and returns the value when the user types in a number. You can then reuse this function to get the input without repeating code like you do in your current solution. You can do something like

```
guess_col = get_int()
guess_row = get_int()
```

Comment: Thank you.
I could use two different functions here, one for each coordinate, however, if I use just one function, then I cannot prompt the user with: Please enter coordinate X and Please enter coordinate Y.
I can only ask a "generic" question: Please enter coordinate (without specifying which one)
Or am I wrong?